How to decided the pod to remove in node?
Is there any way to remove the specific pod that I want?
Example: I have an app that I set replicaCount: 8 pod, that means I have 8 pod in 8 node.
4 node spot instance , 4 node on-demand
In a specific time of the day, I need to scale down pod by HPA. How I can remove 4 pod in spot-instance and still keep 4 pod in on-demand?
Tried to search all of document in Kubernetes but don't find any solutions for this case. Pod-delete-cost, Pod Topology Spread Constraints

Per my understanding, you are asking about selective pod removal based on node types like spot and on-demand instances. when scaling down in Kubernetes, you can use a combination of taints, tolerations, and node selectors or affinity rules to achieve this,

Label Your Nodes

kubectl label node <spot-node-name> instance-type=spot
kubectl label node <on-demand-node-name> instance-type=on-demand


Configure your Deployment to use node affinity rules so that pods can be scheduled on both spot and on-demand nodes. However, make sure you also allow for re-scheduling when scaling down.

     affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: instance-type
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - spot
                      - on-demand


Use Taints and Tolerations to ensure that pods on spot nodes are removed first when scaling down because they tolerate the taint but are not preferred.

kubectl taint nodes <spot-node-name> spot-instance=true:NoSchedule


Then add toleration to the Deployment manifest

      tolerations:
        - key: "spot-instance"
          operator: "Exists"
          effect: "NoSchedule"


Configure HPA to scale based on metrics that reflect the actual load


Another possible option would be setting up a Pod Deletion Cost, which can help specify the order in which pods should be deleted. You can set a higher deletion cost for pods on on-demand instances to prefer deleting pods on spot instances first.

I don't understand clearly what you mean. How can I scale down the pod with that tag node and taint? I'm using HPA to scale down pod, how HPA can detect the pod in node spot-instance to scale down first ?
Example: I scale deployment with 8pod nginx-1, 2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7, 8.
nginx 1 2 3 4 in node on-demand
nginx 5 6 7 8 i node spot-instance.
How I can scale nginx 5 6 7 8 by HPA? or using any way to scale down it with remove specific pod?

To manage pod removal based on node types like spot & on-demand instances in K8s during scaling down
Label nodes to distinguish between spot & on-demand instances.
Configure node affinity to prioritize scheduling new pods on on-demand nodes.
Taint spot nodes to discourage new pod scheduling but allow it if necessary.
Set a higher deletion cost using the controller.kubernetes.io/pod-deletion-cost annotation on pods running on on-demand instances. This ensures that pods on spot instances are deleted first during scaling down.
